# Can I temporarily disable tracker-store and tracker-extract and tracker-miner to help save battery on my laptop?

Tags: power-management, battery, systemd, tracker

I am really disappointed in my battery life on Kubuntu and I notice when I monitor htop, that these systemd daemons really are constantly eating cpu in the background.

[image]

I don't know what they do, but considering how constant they are, I wonder if I could disable them while using my battery so I can save that instead. When Plugged in, they can do what they need to do otherwise.

How can I do this?

Comment: I am on kubuntu 21.04. I do not have such a process running. I thought tracker store was the gnome file indexer. MAybe disabling file indexing would help.

Comment: I am on kubuntu; That might be why its there. In any case, `tracker reset --hard` seemed to have fixed things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following setting, which apparently are not exposed in the user interface:

```
gsettings set org.freedesktop.Tracker.Miner.Files index-on-battery false
```

To reset to default, run

```
gsettings reset org.freedesktop.Tracker.Miner.Files index-on-battery
```

Stopping the miner also stops tracker-store and tracker-extract (leaves them without a job).

On Newer Versions of Gnome.Tracker, the schema changed slightly, it's now Tracker3 instead of Tracker, so `org.freedesktop.Tracker.Miner.Files` becomes `org.freedesktop.Tracker3.Miner.Files`. The rest of the instructions are the same and the key is unchanged.

Comment: @gidoBOSSftw5731 Many thanks for this update!